# Opensplice - Getting the nodeId in C# from a local participant

Tags: c#, data-distribution-service, opensplice

I am using the DCPSParticipant builtin topic to retreive infos about participants on the domain (I'm working with C#).

In the [example](https://github.com/ADLINK-IST/opensplice/blob/master/examples/dcps/BuiltInTopics/cs/src/BuiltInTopicsDataSubscriber.cs#L128), the sample received contains the node identification which can be accessed with :

```cs
int nodeId = data[i].Key[0];
```

Now, I'd like to get the same ID but from a locally created participant. The goal is to correlate a local participant with a [ParticipantBuiltInTopicData](http://download.ist.adlinktech.com/docs/Vortex/apis/ospl/cs_api/html/a01228.html).

In RTI, we can get the GUID of a participant through its instance handle (see [this post](https://community.rti.com/kb/accessing-guid-connext-dds-entities)), however I can't manage to replicate it in C#.

**How can I get the nodeID from a local participant ?**

**Alternatively, can I get the GUID of a local participant ?**

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it, though it seems a bit odd.

After creating the local participant, I'm calling the [GetDiscoveredParticipantData](http://download.ist.adlinktech.com/docs/Vortex/apis/ospl/cs_api/html/a00928.html#abc1ee491dc8e129beec79f982cbd8fe6) using the local participant instanceHandle.

```cs
IDomainParticipant participant = DomainParticipantFactory.Instance.CreateParticipant(DomainId.Default);
InstanceHandle handle = participant.InstanceHandle;
ParticipantBuiltinTopicData selfData = new ParticipantBuiltinTopicData();

participant.GetDiscoveredParticipantData(ref selfData, handle);
Console.WriteLine(selfData.Key[0]); // Node id
```